# how to insert contents to beginning and end of a visual block using vim scripting

Tags: vim

I am new to vim scripting. Is it possible to do the following using **vim scripting**?

I have a visual block of text. By pressing function key (say F5) I need to insert some text to beginning and end of my visual block.

i.e. the following text is in visual block:

**Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum.**

**Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Ipusm doret lorem ipsum.**

On pressing F5 key, the text should be changed to:

**"[[Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum.**

**Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Lorem ipusm doret lorem ipsum. Ipusm doret lorem ipsum.]]"**

The text **"[[** and **]]"** needs to be placed on beginning and end of the visual block. Can anybody give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do this manually? Use `` `< `` to go to the beginning of the visual selection, `i"[[` to insert the text, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to normal mode, repeat at the other end.

In a mapping:

```
:vnoremap <F5> <Esc>g`<i"[[<Esc>g`>a]]"<Esc>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [surround addon](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).  It gives you the ability to take a visual selection or an area defined by a motion (e.g. a word, the text within a pair of parentheses, etc.) and quickly and conveniently surround it with a pair of characters.

Comment: +1: [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) is the best tool for this job!